# In Airflow UI, how to add SQL Server connection type

Tags: airflow

I had set up airflow in my machine using astro CLI as mentioned here https://www.astronomer.io/guides/get-started-airflow-2/ . I wanted to use SQL Server connection in Airflow UI, but I don't see it anywhere.

Can someone tell me how I can add it since I need this provider to access SQL Server tables?

[image]

I am using the airflow version - Astronomer Runtime 5.0.6 based on Airflow 2.3.3+astro.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to pip install the SQL Server provider package.

https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql/

You can edit the Dockerfile that's created by the Astro CLI to install it when the tool brings up the environment.